# Increase separation of qplot points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a qplot generated by the following:

```
qplot(data=data, x=xvar, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable, 
      geom=c("point", "line"), ylim(0, 20000))
```

In the resulting image, the y points are very close to each other. I'd like to make their separation more clear. As you can see I tried using ylim to do this, but that had no effect.

Comment: The solution will be specific to your data. Please post some sample data in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position=position_jitter(w,h)` in your `qplot` you can control the spacing in a scatter plot. For example:

```
qplot(data=data, x=xvar, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable, 
  geom=c("point", "line"), ylim(0, 20000), position=position_jitter(w=0.3, h=0))
```

This causes random sidescatter of the dots in the width direction, but no scatter in the height direction.

Comment: This is good, but why doesnt the line connect with the newly jittered point?

Comment: The representation of the dots is shifted randomly (the dots will be different each time you plot them). The line, however, is based on the original location of the dots and will therefore not be plotted differently.

Comment: If you want the line to connect the points the easiest way is probably to use the (base R) `jitter()` function to create a jittered version of the points before you plot them ...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrie that without example data it is hard to say what you exactly want. I would however take a look at geom_jitter.

http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_jitter.html